# Write a JPG image file in C

Tags: c, image, image-processing, jpeg, file-handling

I read JPEG image file and store its bits to a text file. Now I wanna convert back to valid JPEG image using those bits in the text file. I have tried writing a binary file but it doesn't retrieve the image file.

Please steer me to the right direction. I'm busting my head into this for couple of days but no luck so far.

Here is my code for writing JPG file:

```
int length;
unsigned char *inData;  
char Buffer[9];
int c = 0, x;
/* file.txt has single bit per line. */
FILE *reader = fopen(file.txt, "r"); 
FILE *writer = fopen("output.JPG","wb");

fseek(reader, 0, SEEK_END);
length=ftell(reader);
fseek(reader, 0, SEEK_SET);

for(x=0; x < length; x++){
    fscanf(reader, "%d", &inData);
    if(c <= 8){       /*  reading 8-bits  */
        Buffer[c] = inData;
    } else {
        fwrite(&Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), 1, writer);
        c = 0;
    }
    c++;
}

fclose(reader);
fclose(writer);
```

Here is the code snippet for reading input.JPG and writing its bits to file.txt

```
    char *buffer;
int fileLen;
FILE *file = fopen("inputIM.JPG", "rb");

fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
fileLen=ftell(file);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

buffer=(char *)malloc(fileLen+1);
fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, file);
fclose(file);
convertToBit(&buffer, fileLen);
free(buffer);
}

// convert buffer data to bits and write them to a text file   
convertToBit(void *buffer, int length)
{
int c=0;
int SIZE = length * 8;
unsigned char bits[SIZE + 1];
unsigned char mask = 1;
unsigned char byte ;
int i = 0;
FILE *bitWRT = fopen("file.txt", "w");

for (c=0;c<length;c++)
{
    byte = ((char *)&buffer)[c];

    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        bits[i] = (byte >> i) & mask;
        fprintf(bitWRT, "%d\n", bits[i]);
    }
}
fclose(bitWRT);
}
```

Thanks,

-Sam

Comment: "Store its bits" means? Can you show us your code where you are reading your jpeg image and writing it into text file?

Comment: Without seeing your code, we cannot tell you what you're doing wrong.  My suggestion would be to compare the original input file and the output file, to discover where the differences lay.

Comment: I have added code snippet. output.JPG is a corrupted image file. Where Am I getting wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that you are writing bits and not characters ?

Comment: yes I am 100% sure. file.txt has single bit(0/1) in a line.

Comment: @PavanManjunath: I have read JPEG image file as a binary data into buffer, convert that buffer into bits and write each bit to a text file named file.txt.

Comment: Actually you're writing 9 characters, not 8 bits (see _fwrite_) and you increment _c_ variable after you set it to 0. Moreover you read using the byte count but even the new line character(s) are counted as bytes. It's a little bit messy...

Comment: @Adriano: What should I change to get valid image file?

Answer (score 2):

Try to rewrite as follow (please note that it's a very naive and untested implementation):

```
FILE* pInput = fopen("file.txt", "r"); 
FILE* pOutput = fopen("output.JPG","wb");

unsigned char index = 0, byte = 0;
char line[32]; // Arbitrary, few characters should be enough
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), pInput))
{
    if (line[0] == '1')
        byte = (unsigned char)(byte | (1 << index));

    if (++index == 8)
    {
        fwrite(&byte, 1, 1, pOutput);

        index = 0;
        byte = 0;
    }
}

fclose(pInput);
fclose(pOutput);
```

Assumption: every single **line** of your input file is a single **bit** of the original file (it means that if the original file is, for example, 1024 bytes then you'll have 1024 * 8 = 8192 lines in the text file). Note that because of line terminators and (possibly) different encodings the total length of the file will be greater (at least double).

**EDIT**
To write you may use something like this:

```
void convertToBit(void* pBuffer, size_t length)
{
    FILE* pOutput = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    for (size_t i=0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        unsigned char byte = (unsigned char)pBuffer[i];
        for (int bitIndex=0; bitIndex < 8; ++bitIndex)
        {
            if ((byte & (1 << bitIndex)) != 0)
                fputs("1\n", pOutput);
            else
                fputs("0\n", pOutput);
        }
    }

    fclose(pOutput);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adriano. But still I haven't got a valid image file, unfortunately.

Comment: @Sam can you provide the code you use to write the text file?

Comment: I have added code snippet for reading an input image file and converting into bits. Please help me out

Comment: @Sam currently you're not writing your JPEG file but random staff, see the line:  byte = ((char *)&buffer)[c];

Comment: @Sam updated my answer (but I didn't try so if it doesn't work you may try to debug using a few bytes input file - not a JPEG - filled with known values like 0x55 0xAA)

Answer (score 0):

There's one important thing that must be considered, every file has, at the beginning, a header and at the end, a footer. The jpeg header is FF D8, so if you simply write to the file, you can corrupt this header and the file will be corrupted.

Another important thing, if you want to read an imagem file, have you ever tried to do that with binary mode using fread()/fwrite instead of trying to read it's content with a function that was originally designed to read/write caracters? (I don't know, maybe I'm saying something stupid here, but I would give it a shot)

Sorry about my poor english btw....